# add a min-height to CSS3 multi-columns

Tags: css

Can you add a minimum height to CSS3 multi columns?

I'd rather have a single column when the text only has four lines rather than forcing a single line over to the second column.

For example I would rather:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
sodales id ipsum ipsum mauris
interdum qui congue
nisl quis, turpis tristique
```

Not this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet      nisl quis, turpis tristique
sodales id ipsum ipsum mauris 
interdum qui congue
```

Any advice?

Comment: @Breck can you please post a working snippet for the code you are working with so we can work with that?

Comment: @BrandonMcConnell here is an example page: https://breckyunits.com/startups-and-planes.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no minimum height, but the minimum number of lines at the end of a paragraph on their own at the start of a column are called `orphans` (and the opposite... lines on their own at the start of a paragraph is `widows`). These are CSS properties which columns should honour according to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-css3-multicol-20010118/#the-number), but I've done a quick test in Chrome and it doesn't make any difference. So I guess we have to wait for this to be implemented.

An example of how it should be set up:

```
p.columns {
    column-count: 2;
    orphans: 3
}
```

Comment: This sucks, why not roll it our all at once. Thanks @Nathan

Comment: WebKit is an open-source project, you can contribute your own source code, you can also file a bug if not already done ([Help The Community: Report Browser Bugs](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/07/help-the-community-report-browser-bugs/) ;)

Answer (score 3):

I know, this is an old one. But during my research this thread came up first, so I better share my results. There is a [partial supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=column-fill) attribute called `column-fill` which does, what you and I was looking for.
Partial means, you should use browser-specific prefixes...

```
column-count: 2;
column-width: auto;
column-fill: auto;
```

Here are the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to solve this problem using this code sample

```
columns: 3;
orphans: 4;
column-fill: auto;
```

Adding minimum height can create some problem for small for mobile devices. So I set the minimum number of lines via `orphans` and for fill the 1st column set `column-fill:` to `auto`. I added the sample UI here take a look. Thanks.

```css
body {
  background: #1C1B1B;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.data {
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
  columns: 2;
  orphans: 4;
  column-fill: auto;
}

.demo-balance {
  column-fill: balance;
  columns: 2;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -webkit-column-fill: balance;
  -moz-columns: 2;
  -moz-column-fill: balance;
}
```

```html
<p>Sample 1</p>

<p class="data">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus libero libero, placerat at hendrerit nec, vulputate consectetur nisi. Morbi scelerisque lectus id sapien laoreet accumsan. Nunc eget tincidunt ligula, eget suscipit tellus. </p>


<p>Sample 2</p>

<p class="demo-balance">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus libero libero, placerat at hendrerit nec, vulputate consectetur nisi. Morbi scelerisque lectus id sapien laoreet accumsan. Nunc eget tincidunt ligula, eget suscipit tellus. </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Min-height in columns is now supported by IE 10 and Firefox. In Webkit however the text overflows to the right outside the container as explained already in this two bugreports
[Bug#55740](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=55740)
[Bug#65691](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=65691)